# How to convert list of objects into string and then into byte array

Tags: c#, .net, object

The list contains two objects or more I want to create string with the name of its properties and values.

```
async Task<string> ICsvHandler.CsvHandler()
{
    var employees =  new List<objectModel>();
        
    employees.Add(new objectModel("1234", "543", "", "7865", "filhal null"));
    employees.Add(new objectModel("1234", "543", "0000", "7865", "filhal null"));
    Console.WriteLine(employees);
            
    ExportCsv(employees);
    return null;
}

void ExportCsv<T>(List<T> genericList)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = $"{ DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMDDHHmmss") }{ ".csv" }";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            header += prop.Name + ",";
        header = header.Substring(0, header.Length - 2);
        sb.AppendLine(header);
            
        foreach (var obj in genericList)
        {
            var line = "";
            foreach (var prop in info)
                line += prop.GetValue(obj, null)+"," ;
            
            line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
            sb.AppendLine(line);
            char [] ch= sb.ToString().ToCharArray();
            _cloudStorageService.UploadFileFromMemoryAsync(fileName,ch);
        } 
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I am getting name of the property when I run but not the values of object.
I want to understand why my values are not coming into the `StringBuilder` with `line += prop.GetValue(obj, null) + ",";`. this only shows `,,,,,,,,,`

Expecting name of property along with its values but getting name in header and not values.

Comment: What is the variable `info`?

Comment: Do you mean JSON string?

Comment: Have you tried just `prop.GetValue(obj)`?

Comment: Can you show how the `ObjectModel` class is declared?